# Need a Kanban X Ticketing Software, Open-Source and Self-Hosted?

Tags: project-management, kanban

**Problem Statement:**

We're using scrum at work. Not every member has scrum account. Only senior members have it (I'm not sure why). The 60% employees are among juniors.

So, our purpose is one of the members of the junior team will lead the junior team in assigning tickets. The tickets are already coming in our scrum assigned to our senior members. I don't need a software which asks me to re-write the ticket again. All the ticket assigner should do is:

"Ticket#12345" and assign it to personABCD

The Ticket#12345 is the ticket number in our company's scrum.

He needs to assign the tickets to each member.

Other members view the tickets. I'd prefer other members not being able to delete tickets or move other members tickets to "closed" for the sake of no foul play. It doesn't matter if they can view others tickets or not.

Once personABCD is assigned a ticket number, he goes to our company's scrum, searches the linked ticket and starts doing it. Once done, he needs to be able to add updates to the ticket. Something like 50 word description of how the ticket was solved. And he should put that ticket in "closed".

The next day, the closed tickets should not appear in personABCD's dashboard. Only open tickets should appear. But closed tickets need to be there because the leader will see the closed tickets and understand our progress.

Sending mails to each asignee about ticket is irrelevant but I won't mind that if the mail server setup is easy. (It was dreaded in osticket that I could not do it).

I think what I'm asking for is probably not built it. It's a mixture of kanbana and ticketing software. I've tried zammad, osticket so far. I've also tried kanboard but I'm disappointed with them because they failed to satisfy my purpose.

I tried slack with COMBAN app(not exactly sure of the name but I googled slack kanban). It doesn't have an easy to assign thing. Lots of details pop up to be filled(or optional if you use template). I want the process of assigning tickets to be as simple as going to personABCD user, and just simply writing ticket#12345 there nothing more than that.

I'm hopeful I can find a solution here.

Update: Is there a way to do this using slack and teams using some extensions?